# jQuery .on fails for class

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">
  <label>
    My Label
    <input type="search">
  </label>
</div>
```

This works fine:

```
$('body').on('keypress', '.myclass', function (event) {
        ///do stuff here
    });
```

But this fails:

```
$('.myclass').on('keypress', $('input'), function (event) {
        ///do stuff here
    });
```

I also tried this without success:

```
$('.myclass').on('keypress', function (event) {
        ///do stuff here
    });
```

I don't control the markup, and it seems like I've missed some nuance of jQuery .on delegates.

Can someone explain why selecting the body and then delegating to the class works, but simply selecting the class does not?

Comment: Why not simply `$('.myclass').on('keypress', 'input', function (event) {}`?

Comment: how does that differ from what I put in my original post?

Comment: Your code uses `$('input')` instead of `'input'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said

> I don't control the markup

This led me to believe that you're facing the issue of an `.append()`ed element. If you try to delegate a `.on()` function to (for example) a class that doesn't exist, it won't work. For example:

```
$('.appendedElement').on('keypress', function(event){
  alert("Appened Keypress");
});

$("body").append('<div class="appendedElement"><label>My Appended Label <input type="search"></label></div>');
```

You can see that nothing happens when you type anything into the searchbox.

[Bootply - Failed Event](http://www.bootply.com/XjGEbJMaPp)

However, if you delagate the `.on()` event to a child of `body`it will work:

```
$('body').on('keypress', ".appendedElement", function(event){
  alert("Appened Keypress");
});

$("body").append('<div class="appendedElement"><label>My Appended Label <input type="search"></label></div>');
```

As you can see, the `alert()` function fires correctly.

[Bootply - Success (Body)](http://www.bootply.com/s0RPVXAddQ)

The last example is declaring the `.on()` event following the append:

```
$("body").append('<div class="appendedElement"><label>My Appended Label <input type="search"></label></div>');

$('.appendedElement').on('keypress', function(event){
  alert("Appened Keypress");
});
```

You can see that the `alert()` fires correctly here as well.

[Bootply - Success (Post-append)](http://www.bootply.com/Ny6ketfnwq)

Hopefully this gives you some insight.

Comment: Thanks Tim Lewis for a such a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand how event delegation works?

What happens is you add an event handler that is an ancestor of the element. When you press the key, the event propagates down to the ancestor element through the document tree. So it starts at the input, travels to the inputs parent and the parents, parent, and so on until it reaches the element you hooked the event too.

```
$(TheAncestor).on(TheEvent, TheChild, TheFunction);
```

So when you bind the event, TheAncestor needs to exist. If it does not, no events are bound.

So when you say this does not work

```
$('.myclass').on('keypress', function (event) {
    ///do stuff here
});
```

That means that your "myclass" elements have not been added to the document when you try to attach the events. A simple `console.log($('.myclass').length)` can show there are no elements.

Your code

```
$('body').on('keypress', '.myclass', function (event) {
```

works because the body exists and the event is able to propagate down to it.

Comment: Sorry epascarello Tim Lewis beat you to it.